# Override the theme for the login page

Tags: theming, users

How can I override theme for the user login page in Drupal 7? By default, that page takes the default theme style.

Comment: What do you mean by override? Do you want to use different theme for user login page ? or Do you want to add css to customize user login page look & feel different from default theme ?

Comment: Yes, I mean - feel different from default theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can separate template file for overriding the user-login page.

Just create a template file called **page--user--login.tpl.php** file for theming the login page.

Answer (score 0):

To know all the possibility about functions, variables, and template files for a specific block, region, or page, install the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel), and [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) modules.

In the bottom left corner of your page, you will find the checkbox that actives the Theme developer module. Enable it, and click on a point of your page: You will find all the information about how to theme that part of the page.